# qml (or other) style for QGIS

Tags: qgis, style, mapquest, qml

I have to create a map which is near at the MapQuest style, but for some reason I can't use a Lyer plugin, so I'd like to build the "Background" with files from geofabrik.

Are there qml styles (or other types of files which can be importet to qgis) on the internet, that I can download?

Answer (score 2):

Searching for "QGIS Style" on github.com reveals a few repos with some style files in. The best of all these is probably Anita Graser's styles and related blog post:

https://anitagraser.com/2014/05/31/a-guide-to-googlemaps-like-maps-with-osm-in-qgis/